# Prove $a\cdot (10)^n\equiv a\cdot 1\pmod 3$ using induction.

Tags: induction, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> Prove $a\cdot (10)^n\equiv a\cdot 1\pmod 3$ using induction.

I need to prove this equation to be true not sure how to solve. I know I have to first use one and then plug in $k+1$ but what am I plugging it into a or n and then how do I solve?

Comment: Do you have to use induction?

Comment: The solution without induction is much simpler since $10\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a\cdot 10^k \equiv a \quad(mod3)$$
$$a\cdot 10^{k+1}=a\cdot 10^k\cdot (9+1)\equiv a\cdot 10^k \equiv a \quad(mod3)$$